# How to customize worker selection process through AJP13

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, jboss, mod-jk

In apache load-balancing is there a way to selecting the worker in AJP13 according to our requirement ?

That means if we say currently there are server instances (jboss or tomcat) load balanced with Apache (mod_jk) round robbing. Is there a method or way that can I customize the worker selection process. (other that Round Robbin e.g. According to the CPU usage of the particular server instance )

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [mod_cluster](http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster) from JBoss. I think mod_cluster allows to select works on various criteria like current load etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Available load metrics are:
  - cpu
  - heap
  - sessions
  - requests
  - send-traffic
  - receive-traffic
  - busyness
  - <your own>, i.e. one could easily implement the load interface and craft one's own load metric.